# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac':

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

When I try `$ react-native run-android` on android emulator, I get this error:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/home/user/app/android/app/src/main/java/com/package/MainApplication.java:8: error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of RNAWSCognitoPackage
import com.airlabsinc.RNAWSCognitoPackage;
^
1 error
Incremental compilation of 1 classes completed in 0.448 secs.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.964 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Then I have 2 imports with the same name in my `/home/user/app/android/app/src/main/java/com/package/MainApplication.java`
May this cause the issue?
Is this the issue with RN?

```
package com.package;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.amazonaws.RNAWSCognitoPackage; // 1
import com.amazonaws.amplify.pushnotification.RNPushNotificationPackage;
import com.airlabsinc.RNAWSCognitoPackage; // 2
import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;
import com.toast.ToastPackage;
import com.vdi.VDIPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
```

My env:

```
**Environment**:
  * OS: Linux 4.13
  * Node: 8.9.4
  * Yarn: Not Found
  * npm: 5.6.0
  * Watchman: Not Found
  * Xcode: N/A
  * Android Studio: Not Found

**Packages**: (wanted => installed)
  * react: 16.3.0-alpha.2 => 16.3.0-alpha.2
  * react-native: 0.54.2 => 0.54.2
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682536/6359528

Comment: what is the output of adb devices?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import the same class from different packages in JAVA, I suggest you remove the first import :

```
- import com.amazonaws.RNAWSCognitoPackage; // 1 (remove this line)
```

Comment: Lol I just saw you posted this question a year and half from now :D

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the `build` file in the android folder
2. Delete the build file in `android>app`
3. run `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possibilities, try which one is suitable,

1. You might have missed some initial setup for the package RNAWSCognitoPackage and its related services whatever you used. So check out the installation setup once.
2. If everything is fine, then another case, android stores cache to build faster. Everytime you install a new packages, you should clean the code and run it again.

   remove node_modules and Package-lock.json and run the following commands

   ```js
   cd android

   ./gradlew clean

   ./gradlew cleanBuildCache

   npm install
   ```

Some rare cases, you need to try this,

```js
npx react-native-clean-project clean-project-auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right solution. Can you try it out once!

1. Open your project in Android Studio. Go to File menu and click on Invalidate caches/Restart.
2. Rebuild your project.
3. Execute npm run android or react-native run-android